# What is the elevator pitch for Arduino.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

From **[The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)**

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You
>   have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What
>   would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes
>   what your site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> - the tagline
> - the motto
> - the blurb under the logo
> - a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> - perhaps eventually the domain name [in some form](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)
>
> (Due to a variety of [practical difficulties with domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), we
>   prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain
>   their `topic.stackexchange.com` names indefinitely.)
>
> Naming is hard — *really* hard. But if you can come up with a sensible
>   elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.
>
> For more detail see: [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)

Answer (score 3):

> Arduino: Electronics for makers made easy.

or

> Arduino: Practical microcontroller powered electronics without a BSc.

Comment: Is the question asking us to create an elevator pitch for Arduino or Arduino.SE? I think your answer adresses the former, but should address the latter.

Comment: i would change the first to "Arduino: electronics made easy", plus, what is a BSc? (i've googled the answer, but that's not good for motto!)

Answer (score 2):

> Arduino.SE: The Adventure begins where the books and tutorials end!

*runs*

Answer (score 1):

> Got an Arduino question? Arduino.SE can answer it!

or

> Got an Arduino question? Get it answered at Arduino.SE!

or

> Got an Arduino question? Arduino.SE is the place to get your answers!

That's what I think an Arduino.SE elevator pitch should sound like. Don't you think?

Comment: These are vague and don't really describe our community as a whole. It should intrigue the person who sees this and want to join our site, not just "oh yeah it's cool come and join us." This doesn't differentiate us from any other forum-like site.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Yeah, I guess I didn't get what the question was about. I'll delete the answer altogether...

Comment: Leave it for reference.

Answer (score 1):

## Arduino: Yes! You can!

It may be too short for some of the things, but for moto 2-3 words is perfect size. It is remmembered and pronounced easy. Plus if you start describing something to someone that isn't much into it already, you can lose his interest very fast. Generalized messages like that are more prone to engage a person to delve into the matter. Even if someone have sceptical opinion. 

For example:

1. What, do you want to tell me, you can build a robot with it? 

    Yes! You can!
2. How about a plane or hellicopter?

    Yes! You can!
3. Hmm, how about to make my car or house talk?

    Yes! You can!
4. Sounds intriguing. I'll look into it... and thats my floor.

If we need to *sell* the site to more people, then we need to **sell it**. Not to desribe it.

The above example can be changed a little bit for questions about the site itself.

1. Can I ask there how to do a awesome X?

    Yes! You can!

It could be with different tone:

`Arduino: For all of us!`

Certanly at any case, it shouldn't be dry narrative.

**EDIT:**

I propose something like those or combination of them:

```
All things Arduino! Hardware! Software! People!
All things Arduino! Ideas! Hardware! Software!
```

or variation like that:

```
Everything Arduino! Hardware! Software! People!
Everything Arduino! Ideas! Hardware! Software!
```

I believe that it is descriptive enough, as it basically is summary of the site and still simple and short to be easy remembered and to stuck in the head of people. If we try to be specific, we always will omit something important or we will make it too long. Also on the picture linked by  Annonomus Person, most sites have description about one row, so I believe it will fit there nicely.

P.S. If you like it, or you agree with the general idea, please do post your own opinion or your own sugestions and/or variants. More people participating, the better.

Comment: A great idea: it encourages the user and it does imply a call to action. However, I disagree with this: *Certanly at any case, it shouldn't be dry narrative.* Yes, it shouldn't be dry, but **we need to describe who we are, too. It should be a little bit longer that can be cut down into different parts.** Also, it might be formed into the site switcher "snippet" ([image](http://i.imgur.com/Gf8kLBf.png)), and "Yes, you can!" doesn't fit at all. You should try to add something else to it.

Comment: Well, I aknowledge the shortcomings for something so short, to be description. But the core of my post was, that in this case it should be little bit (or more) like marketing, than pure engeneering. "Site about small form factor open-hardware board for easy development etc." - this kind of description simply will never work very well, if at all. No matter how short or long it is, or how acurate or not it is. This was what I meant by "dry narrative" But you really got me thinking about it now :) I will update my post with new suggestion.

Comment: Nice edit: (this is a tedious process: I updated my answer four times already) but have a few suggestions: 1.) *Ideas!* We don't really supply/discuss ideas here, but I guess it *could* work... 2.) Would you really say "Arduino! Hardware! Software!" to a friend? I love your more modern approach, but it seems like we need a combination of yours and something like mine so we can make the more boring text (for things like the site-switcher) but use yours for advertising: a slice-n-dice is what most sites use.